# Uncheck Selected checkbox on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have already tried all the given methods to uncheck checkbox in jquery, please find my below code.

```
$('#btnDeleteEnterpriseID').click(function () {
       $('#chkbox').prop('checked', false);
       $('#chkbox').removeAttr('checked');
       $('#chkbox').checked = false;
       $('#chkbox').attr('checked', false);
       $('#chkbox input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
       $('#chkbox input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
    });
```

Have tried with all methods that I could get till now.

Below is the code for my checkbox and button.

```
@helper DisplayMultiLine(string str) 
{ foreach (string s in str.Split(new char[] { ',' }))
 { <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" value="@s"class="edit-mode" />@s <br />} 
}
```

Here, @DisplayMultiline is helper class which I used in Web Grid column as shown below,

```
grid.Column(columnName: "EnterpriseID", 
format:@<text><span class="display-mode">
<label id="EnterpriseId" ></label>
</span>@DisplayMultiLine(@item.EnterpriseId)</text>),
```

And I want this checkbox to get unchecked on click event of delete button, code for it given below.

```
<button type="button" id="btnDeleteEnterpriseID" 
value="Delete" class="cancel-user edit-mode" onclick="DeleteEnterpriseID()">Delete</button>
```

I am not getting my mistake, kindly assist.

Kindly note, I have not used all those possibilities together, I just wanted to tell that I have used almost all methods and have tried them one by one.

Comment: do not use all possiblities at the same time

Comment: You are generating duplicate identifiers

Comment: Just use `.prop('checked', false)`.

Comment: @TusharWalzade - I just included those methods to explain I used it all, actually I tried all those possibilities one by one and checked for desired result.

Comment: IDs should be unique, if you are trying to check all boxes using the same id then it won't work, only the first one with that id will change.  Also if that button is in your form, then it won't work as you are not preventing the default action of the button so your form is likely to submit (so your page will reload)

Comment: remove the `onClick` on that button, if you are handling it via jQuery

Comment: @TusharWalzade- I want that Checkbox to get unchecked on Click of delete button so, if you want me to remove onclick event then How can I uncheck those checkbox since there needs to be some event to call that function..isn't it?..Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating duplicate identifiers in your foreach:

```
@helper DisplayMultiLine(string str) 
{ foreach (string s in str.Split(new char[] { ',' }))
 { <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" value="@s"class="edit-mode" />@s <br />} 
}
```

**When you have multiple objects with the same id, jquery is having trouble to distinguish which one of them you aim at**.

*Jquery will either work only on the first one it will match or won't work at all*. **Find a way to distinguish between every check box**. 
for example:

```
@helper DisplayMultiLine(string str) 
int i = 0;
{ foreach (string s in str.Split(new char[] { ',' }))
 { <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" + i value="@s"class="edit-mode" />@s
```

}

```
  i++;

}
```

Comment: Well in that case, I tried to pass enterpriseID which is unique for each row,but still it is not working. Please check below code for passing different id.